# mvc:annotation-driven cause 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

In case I add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to my applicationContext.xml, it causes 404 error on my Tomcat 8.

What is a reason and how can I debug this problem on Tomcat 8? Are any logs to help problem solving like this?

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.kobietydokodu" />
    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> <!-- this cause 404 -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I use Gradle to dependancy managament.

Comment: Hey there, do you have a solution for this? I am getting the same error :(